# Can supervaluationism relate to the abortion debate? If so, how?

Tags: logic

So I'm writing an essay on the Sorites paradox and how it relates to the abortion debate. One resolution to the paradox I was reading about came from supervaluationism, but I'm not entirely sure if or how this resolution could be applied to the abortion debate. Any ideas?

Comment: "the Sorites paradox and the abortion debate" ? Some more details may help...

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA The idea is that if you remove a day from the life of a baby it doesn't stop it being a person. Then repeat this until conception to arrive at the conclusion that personhood begins at conception.

Comment: But neither would a dead human stop being a person?

Comment: @Cell Yeah I'm not really sure what you're trying to argue there

Comment: Well, you said you're not sure if this argument can be applied to the abortion debate. Obviously dead humans are not/have not persons/personhood. Your argument is that personhood is independent of time; reverse time until an adult is an embryo therefore still personhood status, but then what about the opposite? Advance time 3 centuries, still personhood status?

Comment: @Cell That wasn't really the argument. The argument was that it logically follows that personhood begins at conception if you believe a baby is a person. For example the Sorites paradox, as far as I am aware, does not argue that 0 grains is a heap of sand.

Comment: @Cell I'm writing an essay on it and I am honestly just wondering whether supervaluationism  specifically can be used to refute this argument on abortion.

Comment: All I meant was that there are very subtle changes between an old human and a recently deceased human, yet one has personhood and the other does not. However, there are vast differences between an embryo and a baby, but you think the paradox applies here. Anyway welcome to philosophy SE and good luck on your essay.

Comment: Supervaluationism can not be used to refute a sorites argument because it can only be applied on the assumption that the argument is unsound (i.e. that the predicate involved is vague). Nor can it help with figuring out the right cutoff, since it presupposes a selection of acceptable cutoffs as already available for supervaluing, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox/#SupeRela). What it can then do is single out claims that are super-true, i.e. true no matter which cutoff on abortion is adopted. Technical devices aren't meant to solve ethical dilemmas.

Comment: The issue is that "Sorites-like" paradoxes are connected with the *vagueness* of some terms of natural language. The supervaluationst semantics try to define a meaning for statement involving vague predicates, but the vagueness is still there. Thus, it does not give us a way to eliminate vagueness from language (and life).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When confronted with a paradox such as the sorites, there's always the theoretical option of taking the paradoxical argument to be valid and accepting its premises.

Your way of applying sorites reasoning seems to fall into exactly this camp of theoretical possibilities. But then you cannot consistently adopt supervaluationism, since this position takes one of the sorites argument's premises to be false.

Apart from that your idea is interesting. Just a few critical remarks:

1. I would rather consider the vague predicate 'human being' or 'human', since personhood is a philosophically very loaded concept that may bring its own complications that have nothing to do with the abortion debate.
2. Furthermore, I would construct the 'sorites sequence' not as a succession of times but rather as a succession of collections of human cells. This  allows you to have the vague predicate applicable to members of the sorites sequence, which makes things much easier.
3. There are some challenges and problems with your proposal you maybe should address:

Firstly, many have the strong intuition that the sorites argument you use your is not a correct argument. You should give an explanation for that widespread intuition, which is false according to your position.

Secondly, you have a sort of dual sorites your position cannot consistently accept. Your proposed argument uses the non-negated predicate 'human' (I'm using my own example predicate). But you can equally build a sorites with the negated predicate 'non-human', where the sorites sequence is reversed. This sorites starts from the claim that one human cell is not a human being and concludes that one quadrillion human cells (with the right structure) does not make a human being, which seems false. Your adoption of the first sorites as a correct argument forces you to deny the first premise of the dual sorites, but you should give an independent argument for the falsity of that premise.

Peter Unger is virtually the only philosopher accepting some sorites arguments. So, maybe some of his writings on this topic could be of interest to you.